# How Can I Make a Loop of two arrays with some rules

Tags: javascript, react-native, loops

I need some help

**I have two arrays:**

**First array have Boolean elements. (It's true when button is active , and false if not)

The second one strings where "0"(active) or "1" (inactive).**

```
let arrayBotoesCategorias = [iconCategoriaIndividual, iconCategoriaGrupo, iconCategoriaIndoor, iconCategoriaOutdoor, iconCategoriaAquatico,iconCategoriaNatureza];
let arrayCategorias = [item.individual, item.grupo, item.indoor, item.outdoor, item.aquatico, item.natureza];
```

To understand better , PaintBall have grupo(group), indoor, outdoor and natureza(nature) activated. The rest are inactive. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmTVz.png)

```
individual: "0",
grupo: "1",
indoor: "1",
outdoor: "1",
aquatico: "0",
natureza: "1",
```

What I need it's the following but of course with another solution:

```
if(arrayBotoesCategorias[1] == true && arrayBotoesCategorias[2] == true && arrayBotoesCategorias[3] == true && arrayBotoesCategorias[5] == true){
    if(arrayCategorias[1] == "1" && arrayCategorias[2] == "1" && arrayCategorias[3] == "1" && arrayCategorias[5] == "1"){
        return(itemSection)
    }
}
```

When a element from the first array is true and the same position of the second is == "1" , return something.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml1N2.png)

In this example image , I Want to show the images that have those 3 tables (outdoor, aquatico and natureza with value "1");

Comment: what is 'itemSection' ?

Comment: @m_wer itemSection it's a const with the view of each item! As you can see in the images , view with  image, title, etc... from Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved Thanks for the help!

```html
var controlCategorias = 0;
var errorControlCategorias = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i<arrayBotoesCategorias.length; i++){
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[0] && item.individual == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[0] && item.individual == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[0] && item.individual == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[1] && item.grupo == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[1] && item.grupo == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[1] && item.grupo == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[2] && item.indoor == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[2] && item.indoor == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[2] && item.indoor == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[3] && item.outdoor == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[3] && item.outdoor == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[3] && item.outdoor == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[4] && item.aquatico == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[4] && item.aquatico == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[4] && item.aquatico == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if((arrayBotoesCategorias[5] && item.natureza == "1") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[5] && item.natureza == "0") || (!arrayBotoesCategorias[5] && item.natureza == "1"))                        {
                            controlCategorias++;
                        }else{
                            errorControlCategorias++;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                    
            }

            if(controlCategorias > 0 && errorControlCategorias == 0){
                return itemSection;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u need to organize your array like an array of object so that u have options when it comes to validating and the value that changing.

```js
let arrayBotoesCategorias = [
  {
    label: "iconCategoriaIndividual",
    name: "individual",
    value: false
  },
  {
    label: "iconCategoriaGrupo",
    name: "grupo",
    value: false
  },
  {
    label: "iconCategoriaIndoor",
    name: "indoor",
    value: false
  }
];
let arrayCategorias = [
  {
    label: "individual",
    name: "individual",
    value: false
  },
  {
    label: "groupo",
    name: "groupo",
    value: false
  },
  {
    label: "indoor",
    name: "indoor",
    value: false
  }
];

let selectedInput = "individual";

arrayBotoesCategorias.filter((item) => {
  item.value = selectedInput === item.name;
  return item;
});

arrayCategorias.filter((item) => {
  item.value = selectedInput === item.name;
  return item;
});


document.body.innerHTML = ` 
arrayBotoesCategorias ${JSON.stringify(arrayBotoesCategorias)} 
<br>
<br>
arrayCategorias ${JSON.stringify(arrayCategorias)}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```